# Testing a public value that is set in the then of a $q.all() in Angularjs 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test an angular component using [`$componentController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$componentController)
I'm only trying to test inputs and outputs of public code, so in my controller the "`this.data`" property is highest priority. Starting with input of `this.data` is easy as it's just testing the class constructor prop, which is by default set to `undefined`.

**The output is the problem, it has a lot of code to call through before getting the expected value.**

### **Question:**

**How do I attach to $q.all.resolve() and test the `this.data`'s mapped output? The expectation is that `expect(ctrl.data).toEqual(expectedData)`.**

**Controller.js:**

```
class Controller {
  /**
   * @ngInject
   */
  constructor(
      someService, $q, $scope) {
    this.ngScope_ = $scope;
    this.someService_ = someService;
    this.ngQ_ = $q;
    this.data = undefined;
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.getData_();
  }

  getData_() {

    let requests = [1,2];
    const REQUEST_TYPE = 'SOME_REQUEST';
    const outEachApproval = (d) => d[0].approvals;
    const requestsAsArr = requests.split(',');
    const promiseArr = requestsAsArr.map(
        (i) => this.someService.getAllDataByType(
            REQUEST_TYPE, i));

    this.ngQ_.all(promiseArr).then((data) => {
      this.data = data.map(outEachApproval); // How the hell do I test this.data at this point in time in the unit test?
    });
  }
```

Controller_test.js

```
describe('someModule', ()=> {


 let $componentController,
      ctrl,
      $rootScope,
      $q;

  const mockData = [[{approvals: [{name: 'hey'}]},{approvals: [{name: 'hey'}]}]];
  const expectedData = [[{name:'hey'}],[{name:'hey'}]];
  beforeEach(() => {
    module(someModule.name);

    inject((_$componentController_, _$rootScope_, _$q_) => {

      $componentController = _$componentController_;
      $q = _$q_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    });


    ctrl = $componentController(COMPONENT_NAME,
    {
      $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
      someService: {
        getAllDataByType: () => {
          return Promise.resolve(mockData);
        }
      }
    }, {});
  });

  describe('this.data input', ()=> {
    it('should be undefined', () => {
      expect(ctrl.data).toBeUndefined();
    });
  });

  describe('this.data output', ()=> {
    it('should be equal to expectedData after init', (done) => {
      ctrl.$onInit();
      expect(ctrl.data).toEqual(expectedData);
      ctrl.ngScope_.$apply();
      done();    
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several ways to deal with it:

### First

First let your `someService` mock to be available in your tests:

```
let someServiceMock = {
  getAllDataByType: () => {
    //we can leave this empty
  }
};

...

beforeEach(() => {

...

  ctrl = $componentController(COMPONENT_NAME,
  {
    $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
    someService: someServiceMock
  }, {});

});
```

Then in your tests simply spy on it:

```
describe('this.data output', ()=> {
  it('should be equal to expectedData after init', (done) => {
    //as we use $q.all(), we need to create array of promises
    let deferred1 = $q.defer();
    ...
    let deferredN = $q.defer();
    let arrayOfPromises = [deferred1.promise, ... ,deferredN.promise];
    //then we spy on needed method and mock its return value
    spyOn(someServiceMock, 'getAllDataByType').and.returnValue(arrayOfPromises);
    ctrl.$onInit();
    expect(someServiceMock.getAllDataByType).toHaveBeenCalled();
    //now we resolve our promises with any data we want
    let resolveData1 = /*Promise#1 mocked data*/;
    deferred1.resolve(resolveData1)
    let resolveData2 = /*Promise#2 mocked data*/;
    deferred2.resolve(resolveData2)
    ...
    let resolveDataN = /*Promise#N mocked data*/;
    deferredN.resolve(resolveDataN)
    //$q.all() returns array, so expectedData would be array
    let expectedData = [
      resolveData1,
      resolveData2,
      ...
      resolveDataN
    ];
    //then we need to apply changes
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(ctrl.data).toEqual(expectedData);
    ctrl.ngScope_.$apply();
    done();    
  });
});
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/4nkPAhW4uaFPfrY4v10j?p=preview) is a simple plunker to play with multiple `$q.defer()` instances.

Btw, if requests in `someServiceMock.getAllDataByType()` are implemented via angular [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), then you can mock them with [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) service.

---

### Second

Create a mock for `$q` service in your component controller:

```
let $qMock = {
  all: () => {
    //we can leave this empty
  }
}

...

beforeEach(() => {

...

  ctrl = $componentController(COMPONENT_NAME,
  {
    $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
    someService: {
      getAllDataByType: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(mockData);
      }
    },
    $q: $qMock
  }, {});

});
```

Then in your tests simply spy on it:

```
describe('this.data output', ()=> {
  it('should be equal to expectedData after init', (done) => {
    let deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn($qMock, 'all').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    ctrl.$onInit();
    expect($qMock.all).toHaveBeenCalled();
    deferred.resolve(expectedData);
    //now we need to apply changes
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(ctrl.data).toEqual(expectedData);
    ctrl.ngScope_.$apply();
    done();    
  });
});
```

This test is simpler, but notice that it doesn't depend on what `someService.getAllDataByType()` will return.

---

**Some useful articles on subject:**

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
- http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you pass resolve data through local `outEachApproval` function. So in my answer `expectedData` should be replaced by `expectedData = expectedData.map(outEachApproval)`. But you better to init `outEachApproval` as controller method to be able to use it in tests. For example,  `let  outEachApproval = ctrl._outEachApproval` (in tests).